# How to query search on Metadata_storage_path field in Azure Search

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am aware that metadata_storage_path is encoded with Base-64 and we can decrypt it in our code by retrieving results from the Azure Search

My Problem is that I wanted Azure Search to query upon paths present in metadata_storage_path

For e.g. lets say `metadata_storage_path` has values like 
`<baseurl>/india/health` or `<baseurl>/pakistan/health` in its decrypted form, I wanted to search with India text get the relavant files and data

How can I perform a query on the path.?

Comment: Can’t you convert your search string (/India/) to base64 encoded string and send it to Azure Search?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with the previous answer is that `metadata_storage_name` is just a blob name (*not* the entire path) and therefore is not guaranteed to be unique, so it's not a safe primary key.

A safer approach is to "rename" `metadata_storage_path` into a new field (say, "filename") using a [field mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-indexer-field-mappings). That field won't be encoded so it's convenient to retrieve, while the encoded `metadata_storage_path` will still be used for a (safely unique) primary key.

Comment: Yeah , you are right , This is much better and proper solution. never knew about Field Mapping , Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 0):

By default, If you create an index of azure storage it creates an Index on column metadata_storage_path , and that is the reason it is encoded , easiest way to avoid metadata_storage_path decoding is to switch the primary key to something else mostly metadata_storage_name.

Once you change it to something , metadata_storage_path will be available as a plain text

Hope this is useful.

Comment: How do u change the primary key?